# Returning different page content using DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing

I was wondering if doing a "redirect" into a subclass of DelegatingHandler would be possible.
I'm going to explain with an example:

My route, in Global.asax, is as follows

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "SavedSearch",
    routeTemplate: "savedSearch/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: null,
    handler: new SavedSearchDispatcher());
```

`SavedSearchDispatcher` is the name of the subclass of `DelegatingHandler`.

Inside i tried to do the following

```
newUri = new Uri("http://localhost/default.aspx"); //<-- this is an authorized page
HttpRequestMessage rqNew = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, newUri);
HttpResponseMessage message = await base.SendAsync(rqNew, cancellationToken);
```

But instead of getting the content of `newUri`, I'm getting a 404 error

I even tried to get a `HttpResponseMessage` using `HttpClient` which worked partially: I get the login form instead of the page content.

I've got the feeling that I'm a step away from the solution... unless I'm fooling myself.

Comment: It sounds to me like your client is authenticated, but your server is not. So you can either send a regular 307 redirect to your client and have them request the uri, or you can authorize your server to get the page on behalf of the client.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. In fact I thought to use the client authentication to complete the `SendAsync` but I really don't know the way to do it.
I tried to instantiate an `HttpClient` with a `HttpClientHandler` which has a `Credentials` property... but I don't have any user credentials, only a `Principal` instance in `WebProfile`... I suppose this is the reason why I keep getting the login form instead of the page

Comment: Exactly. This isn't allowed because it's a security risk. You're wanting to do "delegation" which isn't enabled through web servers. There's probably ways to get it working but you're going deep into security world where one mistake is a cracker's dream. I recommend you first consider alternatives (e.g., 307), and if that isn't acceptable then outsource it to someone like [Dominick Baier](http://leastprivilege.com/) of [ThinkTecture](http://www.thinktecture.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the info. Alas I chose another path: redirect to a single route (backed by an empty web form this time) which manages the data and put them temporarily in session. Then the page redirects to the intended page... I know, even my nose wrinked but I couldn't afford to spend much more time on it.